# java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.Long$ cannot be cast to java.lang.Long

Tags: scala

I'm getting the error:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.Long$ cannot be cast to java.lang.Long issue in scala.

I tried the various ways to get that value

```
  for (beaconId <- flattenedBeaconList.flatten(flat2).distinct.toList) {
    //val beaconId1 = beaconId.asInstanceOf[Int].asInstanceOf[Long]
    //val beaconId1 = scala.Long.unbox(beaconId)
    //val beaconId1 = Try(beaconId.asInstanceOf[Number].longValue()).toString
    //val beaconId1 = beaconId.m
    val beaconId1: Long = beaconId.asInstanceOf[Long].toLong
    //println("The Beacon ID issssssss::::::" + beaconId1)
    val beacon = dal.Beacons.getById(beaconId1.toLong, brandId)
    //val beaconPayload = dal.Beacons.beaconPayloadByBeaconId(beacon.id.get, brandId).get
    //val beacondIdValue = beaconId.asInstanceOf[Number].longValue()
    //println("Getting called inside the beacon loop::::::::::" + beacondIdValue)
    //val beaconDetails = dal.Beacons.getById(beaconId1, brandId)
    //println("Major value for Beacon is::::::::::" + beaconPayload)
  }
```

Comment: What type is `flattenedBeaconList`?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to cast the companion object of `scala.Long` to `java.lang.Long`, but it is impossible to see why without the definitions of `flattenedBeaconList` and `flat2`.

Comment: def flat2(any: Any): List[Any] =
    any match {
      case i: List[_] => i
      case _ => List(any)
    }

Comment: val flattenedBeaconList = List(Long) 
activeBeacon :: flattenedBeaconList  
activeBeacon is List of Scala.Long.  flat2 function is used to flatten the list to remove duplicates in the list.